# How to prevent multiple error message getting displayed in the angular html?

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

Hi the following is a snippet of code in my angular html file. I am trying to implement an if elseif(condition) elseif(condition) using `ngif` and `ng-container`.

What I want to achieve is only one code block should print the error. In other words I don't want to print two error messages. I don't know why my code is not working.

For example, currently if 
`formGroup.hasError('invalidPasswordStrength')` and `formGroup.hasError('blacklistedPassword')` are true it prints two error messages.

What I expect is if both of them are true I want to print the error message pertaining to `formGroup.hasError('invalidPasswordStrength')` .

I have tried options like this for example:

`*ngIf="formGroup.hasError('passwordConfirmation') && !(formGroup.hasError('invalidPasswordStrength') || formGroup.hasError('blacklistedPassword'))`.

It works but it is not clean

```
<ng-container *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('passwordConfirmation'); else second">
          <alert type="danger" dismissable="false">
            {{ 'VALIDATION.ERRORS.MATCHING_PASSWORDS' | translate }}
          </alert>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container #second *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('invalidPasswordStrength'); else third">
          <alert type="danger" dismissable="false">
            {{ 'VALIDATION.ERRORS.PASSWORD_STRENGTH_INVALID' | translate }}
          </alert>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container #third *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('blacklistedPassword'); else fourth">
          <alert type="danger" dismissable="false">
            {{ 'VALIDATION.ERRORS.PASSWORD_NOT_PERMITTED' | translate }}
          </alert>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container #fourth *ngIf="formGroup.hasError('passwordMatchingUserDetails')">
          <alert type="danger" dismissable="false" >
            {{ 'VALIDATION.ERRORS.PASSWORD_MATCHING_USER_DETAILS' | translate }}
          </alert>
        </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not handle this logic in the validator. I would just do one validator and handle all the errors there, there you can also add them in the order you want. So pseudocode:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['']
  }, { validator: this.myValidator});
}

myValidator(form: FormGroup) {
  // begin every time by removing all errors
  if (form) {
    form.setErrors(null);
    if ('some conditions here') {
      return { 'err1': true }
    }
    if ('some conditions here') {
      return { 'err2': true }
    }
    if ('some conditions here') {
      return { 'err3': true }
    }
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
```

This validator then just returns one error at a time (if error exists).

Answer (score 1):

Remove ngcontainers and try to use this approach.

you can use  instead of  what I have used here.

```
                      <div
                        *ngIf="aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').invalid && (aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').dirty || aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').touched)">

                        <div class="text-danger pull-left" *ngIf="aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors['required']">Passphrase is required.
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-danger pull-left" *ngIf="aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.minlength && !aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.spaceatstart && !aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.spaceatend && !aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.specialatstart && !aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.specialatend && !aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.twospace">
                          Minimum 8 character
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-danger pull-left" *ngIf="aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.maxlength">
                          Maximum 64 character allowed
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-danger pull-left" *ngIf="aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.spaceatstart && !aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.spaceatend">
                          Should not start with a space!
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-danger pull-left" *ngIf="aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.spaceatend && !aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.spaceatstart">
                          Should not end with a space!
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-danger pull-left" *ngIf="aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.spaceatend && aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.spaceatstart">
                          Should not start & end with a space!
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-danger pull-left" *ngIf="aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.noTwoSpaces && !aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.spaceatstart && !aaaServerForm.get('proxy_passphrase').errors.spaceatend">
                          Consecutive spaces not allowed
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```